# Как восспользоваться библеотекой JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Не работает jQuery. Не могу подключить его. И не понимаю в чем может быть проблема. Ведь файлы подключены в правильном порядке. И пути указаны правильно.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello!");
</script>
```

Обычный js скрипт типа алерт срабатывает 
[image: alert]

Но при попытке воспользоваться библиотекой никак не реагирует

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(.block).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello");
    });;
</script>
```

[image: На клик ничего не происходит]

Comment: Прежде чем пользоваться библиотекой, хотя бы немного с синтаксисом ознакомьтесь :(

Comment: грубо ты, почему бы просто не указать на ошибку

Comment: @GENESIS, потому что ответ уже дали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что когда указываешь класс нужно ставить кавычки)

```js
    $('.block').on('click', function() {

        alert("Hello");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">Кнопка</div>
```